# Can I run Armory on a Chromebook?

Tags: armory, coldstorage

I want to buy a cheap computer to use exclusively as a secure offline wallet for cold storage. I am considering a Chromebook.

Has anyone managed to run Armory on a Chromebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Armory appears to be written in C++ and Python, two languages that are not supported by ChromeOS by default. You can take a look at the Armory source code [here.](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory)

Because ChromeOS doesn't support these languages, there is no way to run Armory on a Chromebook without significant modifications, like rooting the device to get to the system shell or formatting the disk and installing Linux. I have heard of people doing both of these things in the past, but I'm not sure which specific device is required or how much effort they take.

If you are looking for a cheap computer to use for this sort of thing, the simplest bet in my opinion would be to purchase a low cost Linux desktop/laptop. This would provide you much more flexibility in what client you use, and would also help keep your wallets private. ChromeOS is pretty secure when it comes down to it, but Google+ is integrated very deeply with the OS, which may not be desirable for what you want to do.